# Implement the removeDuplicates() method in the linked list class

Tags: c++, oop

```
#ifndef INT_LINKED_LIST
    #define INT_LINKED_LIST
    using namespace std;
    class IntSLLNode {
    public:
        IntSLLNode() {
        next = 0;
        }
        IntSLLNode(int el, IntSLLNode *ptr = 0) {
        info = el; next = ptr;
        }
        int getInfo() const
        {
            return this->info;
        }
        IntSLLNode getNext() const
        {
            return this->next;
        }
    private:
        int info;
        IntSLLNode *next;
    };
    
    class IntSLList {
    public:
        IntSLList() {
            head = tail = 0;
        }
        ~IntSLList();
        int isEmpty() {
            return head == 0;
        }
        void addToHead(int);
        void addToTail(int);
        int deleteFromHead(); // delete the head and return its info;
        int deleteFromTail(); // delete the tail and return its info;
        void deleteNode(int);
        bool isInList(int) const;
        void removeDuplicates();
    private:
        IntSLLNode *head, *tail;
    };
    #endif
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a free-coding servide and an order to implement something is not accepted. Please read our [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Its not my homework

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes this question has a not-so-clear title, a code snipped and no text, you really should make things clear when you post a question so that people can understand what you want

Comment: i want to do an implement to the remove duplicates

Comment: "I want..." is **not** a question.  Please take a deeper look at the [tour] and read [ask] to get a better sense of how Stack Overflow works.  We are not here to do your work.

Comment: *Its not my homework* -- Informally, it is homework.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method: remove all occurrences of the first element except the first, remove all occurrences of the second element except the first, ...  and so on until you've passed the last element.

Assuming that you have

```
IntSLLNode* deduplicate(IntSLLNode* start)
```

which removes all duplicates of `start->info` from its following nodes and returns a possibly updated tail pointer, you can write

```
void removeDuplicates()
{
    IntSLLNode* current = head;
    while (current)
    {
        tail = deduplicate(current);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Implementing `deduplicate` left as an exercise.